# Find $n$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0}x^n\frac{\phi_2(x)}{\phi_1(x)}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$ are two linearly indpendend solution of

$$2x^2y''-(x+x^2)y'+(x^2-2)y=0$$

such that $\phi_1(0)=0$
, then find the  smallest positive integer $n$ such that  $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}x^n\frac{\phi_2(x)}{\phi_1(x)}=0$

i have tried lots of examples but not getting anywhere, and i have no idea how to deal this second order linear homogeneous differential equation. Please provide me a hind so that i can solve this further, or is there any short trick to solve this?

Comment: @PierreCarre my bad , i will edit this

Comment: @PierreCarre , i have edited the question i made a mistake while writing the fraction.

Comment: If the equation also holds at $x=0$, we can see that $\phi_i(0)=\phi'_i(0)=0$, but that $\phi''_i(0)$ is not necessarily zero. Not sure if this helps. In the book by Arnold you can find nice results for this kind of linear problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$2x^2y''-(x+x^2)y'+(x^2-2)y=0$$
The solutions of this ODE involves confluent hypergeometric functions. This "brute force" approach would be too arduous.

We can look for approximate solutions valid close to $x=0$, which are solutions of
$$2x^2y''-xy'-2y=0$$
because $(x+x^2)\simeq x$ and $(x^2-2)\simeq -2$ at small $|x|$. Solving this "simplified" ODE leads to :

$$y=c_1x^2+c_2x^{-1/2}\quad\implies\quad \Phi_1\simeq x^2\quad\text{and}\quad \Phi_2\simeq x^{-1/2}$$
$$x^n\frac{\Phi_2}{\Phi_1}=x^{n-2-\frac12}=x^{n-\frac52}$$
The smallest $n$ in order to have $\lim_{x \to 0}x^n\frac{\phi_2(x)}{\phi_1(x)}=0$ is
$$n=3$$